# Add Bcc In Magento Email Model

Tags: magento

i would like to add the bcc using below magento model.

i have tried to add `addBcc('')`        with below model.

But does not work.

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
                    ->setToName($senderName)
                    ->setToEmail($customerEmail)                    
                    ->setBody($processedTemplate)
                    ->setSubject('Subject')
                    ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
                    ->setFromName($senderName)
                    ->setType('html')
                    ->send();
```

Any Help Much Appreciation!
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Mage_Core_Model_Email` class does not support bcc (or cc). You need to override the `send` method and add this code right before `$mail->send();`.

```
if ($this->getBcc()) {
    $mail->addBcc($this->getBcc());
}
```

After that your code can be:

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
                ->setToName($senderName)
                ->setToEmail($customerEmail)                    
                ->setBody($processedTemplate)
                ->setSubject('Subject')
                ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
                ->setFromName($senderName)
                ->setType('html')
                ->setBcc('test@example.com') //bcc line added
                ->send();
```

Comment: How to send the Bcc emails to more than one email ids ?

Comment: just use `setBcc` with an `array` as parameter `->setBcc(array('t1@example.com', 't2@example.com'))`

Comment: how can use it for by custom model & when I used these $this->getBcc() I'll get error.

Comment: I try setBcc but not work. no email receive on bcc address. but if email not goes to setToEmail than setBcc work

Comment: @Marius array not working in Bcc. I checked on 2.3.3. NOTE: Single email as string is working but not working when passing multiple emails.

Comment: @Vish I think this answer was for Magento 1.

Comment: @Marius Okay :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this option. Please note that! If your using AWS, Bcc option didn't work. This is AWS potion and read their policy. Hope help

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                ->setToName($senderName)
                ->setToEmail($customerEmail)
                ->addBcc('jondoe@exmaple.com')                    
                ->setBody($processedTemplate)
                ->setTemplateSubject('Subject')
                ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
                ->setFromName($senderName)
                ->setType('html')
                ->send();
```

You can also used like this snippets

```
 $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
 $emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_email');
 $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('My Subject');
 $emailTemplate->setSenderName('Store Name');
 $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('jondoe@exmaple.com');
 $emailTemplate->addBcc('jane@doe.com'); 
 $emailTemplateVariables['price'] = $currencySymbol.number_format($_product->getFinalPrice(), 2);
 $emailTemplateVariables['productname'] = $_product->getName();
 $emailTemplate->send($email, 'My Store', $emailTemplateVariables);`
```